# Why NullPointerException happens with usage of standard BillingService?

Tags: android, binding, service

I use standard `BillingService` in my application (i.e. copied from the [sample application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) without changes).
But sometimes my app crashes with the following data in logcat:

```
04-16 10:05:43.556: INFO/ActivityManager(96): Start proc tv.kinobaza.app for service tv.kinobaza.app/tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService: pid=28748 uid=10081 gids={3003}
04-16 10:05:43.646: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(28748): Shutting down VM
04-16 10:05:43.656: WARN/dalvikvm(28748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService@4632f578 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3282)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService.onStart(Unknown Source)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3267)
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     ... 10 more
04-16 10:05:43.736: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(96): Layer::setBuffers(this=0xb947a8), pid=96, w=1, h=1
04-16 10:05:43.736: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(96): Layer::setBuffers(this=0xb947a8), pid=96, w=1, h=1
04-16 10:05:43.766: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(96): Layer::requestBuffer(this=0xb947a8), index=0, pid=96, w=480, h=418 success
04-16 10:05:43.986: DEBUG/dalvikvm(28721): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9604 objects / 1369120 bytes in 102ms
```

Here is the related code:

```
/**
 * We don't support binding to this service, only starting the service.
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent, startId);
}
```

What is wrong here?

What I've noticed - when device sleeps during the night, once I start use it, it crashes within ~5 minutes.

And, here are more details: `BillingService` started from the Preferences screen of my application. Here the code from the `Preferences` class:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
mBillingService.unbind();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Upd. Probably, I should start this service/unbind in the Main activity?

Here is my proguard.cfg:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-libraryjars /lib/libGoogleAnalytics.jar
-libraryjars /lib/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /lib/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial for another perspective: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Comment: I assume your package is tv.kinobaza? I don't understand as the stacktrace gives an Unknown Line error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:05:43.656: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28748):     at tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService.onStart(Unknown Source) , have you proguarded your app?

Comment: Yes, this is the main package. tv.kinobaza.billing - the package where BillingService is. And yes, the app has been proguarded.

Comment: So you get this NPE after proguard and not beforehand? You must be obfuscating something that you shouldn't like a class extending Application/Activity/Service

Comment: I am getting it after project export from Eclipse. So, after proguard. Should I include BillingService into proguard exclusion list?

Comment: Erm I'm not fully sure, but if you comment out the proguard for the time being, see if you still get the NPE, then you can fix the problem

Comment: Yes you should not obfuscate classes that extend service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you get this NPE after proguard and not beforehand.

You must be obfuscating something that you shouldn't like a class extending Application/Activity/Service

You should not obfuscate these classes:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html (Goto Example 7)

Comment: Looks like this is already handled in my proguard.cfg - posted it. I've renamed proguard.cfg to proguard.cfg.bak - hope it allows to skip obfuscating. Testing it now.

Comment: Ok, looks like it works well now. @Blundell, could you please help me to understand what I need to correct in my proguard.cfg (posted in the question)? Thank you.

Comment: I can't really help as I'd have to see the whole project, if you add '-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable' to your proguard.cfg this will allow you too see where your errors are happening after obfuscation

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out the obvious but if proguard were the problem, then we wouldn't see his billing service name in the stack trace. (we would see an obfuscated name, and not tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService.onStart).

Try this [Why Android service crashes with NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856861/why-android-service-crashes-with-nullpointerexception)