# Why Android service crashes with NullPointerException?

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, android-service

Here is the code:

```
public class BillingService extends Service implements ServiceConnection {
...
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handleCommand(intent, startId); // line 361
    }

    /**
     * The {@link BillingReceiver} sends messages to this service using intents.
     * Each intent has an action and some extra arguments specific to that action.
     * @param intent the intent containing one of the supported actions
     * @param startId an identifier for the invocation instance of this service
     */
    public void handleCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Debug.Yes) {
            Log.i(TAG, "handleCommand() action: " + action);
        }
        if (Consts.ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
            String[] notifyIds = intent.getStringArrayExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
            confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
        } else if (Consts.ACTION_GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION.equals(action)) {
            String notifyId = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
            getPurchaseInformation(startId, new String[] { notifyId });
        } else if (Consts.ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            String signedData = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNED_DATA);
            String signature = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNATURE);
            purchaseStateChanged(startId, signedData, signature);
        } else if (Consts.ACTION_RESPONSE_CODE.equals(action)) {
            long requestId = intent.getLongExtra(Consts.INAPP_REQUEST_ID, -1);
            int responseCodeIndex = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.INAPP_RESPONSE_CODE,
                    ResponseCode.RESULT_ERROR.ordinal());
            ResponseCode responseCode = ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
            checkResponseCode(requestId, responseCode);
        }
    }
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService@45129a30 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at tv.kinobaza.billing.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:361)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
... 10 more
```

Comment: What code does line 361 point to in your BillingService.java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the most likely cause would be because `intent` would be `null`. According to the documentation for [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)):

> `intent`
>
> The `Intent` supplied to `startService(Intent)`, as given. This may be `null` if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`

Comment: What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: @Jean Hominal, what should I do if `intent == null`?

Comment: @LA_: Have you checked (in a debugger, for example), that intent was null? After that, if you find that the given intent *is* null, then... it is your application. Re-read the documentation snippet I quoted - it explains in which case it could be null. After that, you - and the ones developing your application - are the only ones that can decide what to do. (eg, You can either avoid having a null Intent altogether, or you can decide to do nothing.)

Comment: @Jean Hominal, I am not able to catch that in debugger - it happens in a few hours (~12) after service start.

Comment: @LA_: Which seems to match the conditions for receiving a `null` intent - your service was probably stopped to reclaim system resources, and restarted without an intent - meaning that it was received without a user having made an action. I believe you can ignore it in that case.

Comment: @Jean Hominal, I can not just ignore this - error message is shown to the user.

Comment: @LA_: By "ignoring", I meant that you could put a `null` check and `return;` when that is the case (and probably log what happened if debug mode is active.)

Comment: I got the same error, ie. null intent pointer after about 12 hours. I had `return START_STICKY`, and have changed it to `return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: How to avoid double calling to task handleCommand(intent, startId); as both onStart() and onStartCommand will be called? is it a good design? @Rookie